# What is the actual i18n for the support of Nepali language as like es for spain and it for italy

Tags: grails

As there are country code in i18n in grails for the country languages like messages_es.properties for Spain, messages_it.properties for Italy.  I want same for the Nepali language. I have tried for messages_np_NP.properties but not working for me as it shows ??????? in my view page. So what is the actual correct code for Nepali language?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ones:

```
{ne-np} Nepal Nepali; 
{ne-in} India Nepali
```

Answer (score 0):

M
You can customize your own message properties file in grails under i18n>>Resources Bundle'messages'that ends with country locale you are interested. Example: messages_en_GB.properties for British English.